# I need to save a mp4 file in a object so I can store it in a link list. is it possible?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm creating a media player where you can open a file using filechooser and then save it automatically in a data structure, but my problem is I can't get the file path using only a filechooser when I'm opening a file.

What I want to do is select a file using filechooser and then locates the filepath, store it in a object then pass it into a link list.

Any help?

PS: it's just a prototype of a media player just practicing how to do it

Comment: Java, my fault for using wrong tags

Comment: Filechooser returns file object for selected file, you can use file object to reference selected file